# LAN Gaming with iOS - VPN Server has trouble with broadcasting packets

Tags: ios, vpn, lan

I am attempting to setup a VPN server on my Raspberry Pi with a local bridge to my home's LAN so that my brothers, who live elsewhere, can play Civilization 6 with me on their iPhones. I have set up the VPN and bridge according to this [guide](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/A._Examples_of_Building_VPN_Networks/10.4_Build_a_Generic_Remote_Access_VPN) and am able to connect to the VPN and can even play a multiplayer game between my iPad and iPhone.

But here's the catch: I can only play the multiplayer game when the game host device (my iPad in this case) is connected to the VPN and the other device (my iPhone) is connected to my WiFi. The game cannot be played when both devices are connected to the VPN. The game also cannot be played when the WiFi-connected device (iPhone) attempts to be the game host.

After investigating with Wireshark I found that the game lobby relies on UDP broadcasting which the VPN somehow messes up. I am not well-versed in networking but am here to learn and am willing to edit this post to make it useful to as many other non-networking experts as possible. Thank you.

**Update:** I expect that this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349728/airprint-over-vpn) is closely related

Details:

- I am using SoftEther (4.34) for my server, installed on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+
- My RPi is connected directly via ethernet to my router
- The VPN type is L2TP to allow iOS devices to connect
- Here is my server's configuration file

```
declare root
{
    uint ConfigRevision 38
    bool IPsecMessageDisplayed true
    string Region US

    declare DDnsClient
    {
        bool Disabled false
        byte Key removingForPrivacy
        string LocalHostname raspberrypi
        string ProxyHostName $
        uint ProxyPort 0
        uint ProxyType 0
        string ProxyUsername $
    }
    declare IPsec
    {
        bool EtherIP_IPsec true
        string IPsec_Secret removingForPrivacy
        string L2TP_DefaultHub CivHub
        bool L2TP_IPsec true
        bool L2TP_Raw true

        declare EtherIP_IDSettingsList
        {
            declare *
            {
                byte EncryptedPassword removingForPrivacy
                string HubName CivHub
                string UserName ben.stringer
            }
        }
    }
    declare ListenerList
    {
        declare Listener0
        {
            bool DisableDos false
            bool Enabled true
            uint Port 443
        }
        declare Listener1
        {
            bool DisableDos false
            bool Enabled true
            uint Port 992
        }
        declare Listener2
        {
            bool DisableDos false
            bool Enabled true
            uint Port 1194
        }
        declare Listener3
        {
            bool DisableDos false
            bool Enabled true
            uint Port 5555
        }
    }
    declare LocalBridgeList
    {
        bool DoNotDisableOffloading false

        declare LocalBridge0
        {
            string DeviceName eth0
            string HubName CivHub
            bool LimitBroadcast false
            bool MonitorMode false
            bool NoPromiscuousMode false
            bool TapMode false
        }
    }
    declare ServerConfiguration
    {
        bool AcceptOnlyTls true
        uint64 AutoDeleteCheckDiskFreeSpaceMin 104857600
        uint AutoDeleteCheckIntervalSecs 300
        uint AutoSaveConfigSpan 300
        bool BackupConfigOnlyWhenModified true
        string CipherName AES128-SHA
        uint CurrentBuild 9745
        bool DisableCoreDumpOnUnix false
        bool DisableDeadLockCheck false
        bool DisableDosProction false
        bool DisableGetHostNameWhenAcceptTcp false
        bool DisableIntelAesAcceleration false
        bool DisableIPsecAggressiveMode false
        bool DisableIPv6Listener false
        bool DisableJsonRpcWebApi false
        bool DisableNatTraversal false
        bool DisableOpenVPNServer false
        bool DisableSessionReconnect false
        bool DisableSSTPServer false
        bool DontBackupConfig false
        bool EnableVpnAzure false
        bool EnableVpnOverDns true
        bool EnableVpnOverIcmp true
        byte HashedPassword removingForPrivacy
        string KeepConnectHost keepalive.softether.org
        uint KeepConnectInterval 50
        uint KeepConnectPort 80
        uint KeepConnectProtocol 1
        uint64 LoggerMaxLogSize 1073741823
        uint MaxConcurrentDnsClientThreads 64
        uint MaxConnectionsPerIP 256
        uint MaxUnestablishedConnections 1000
        bool NoHighPriorityProcess false
        bool NoLinuxArpFilter false
        bool NoSendSignature false
        string OpenVPNDefaultClientOption dev-type$20tun,link-mtu$201500,tun-mtu$201500,cipher$20AES-128-CBC,auth$20SHA1,keysize$20128,key-method$202,tls-client
        string OpenVPN_UdpPortList 1194
        bool SaveDebugLog false
        byte ServerCert removingForPrivacy
        byte ServerKey removingForPrivacy
        uint ServerLogSwitchType 4
        uint ServerType 0
        bool StrictSyslogDatetimeFormat false
        bool Tls_Disable1_0 false
        bool Tls_Disable1_1 false
        bool Tls_Disable1_2 false
        bool Tls_Disable1_3 false
        bool UseKeepConnect true
        bool UseWebTimePage false
        bool UseWebUI false

        declare GlobalParams
        {
            uint FIFO_BUDGET 1000000
            uint HUB_ARP_SEND_INTERVAL 5000
            uint IP_TABLE_EXPIRE_TIME 60000
            uint IP_TABLE_EXPIRE_TIME_DHCP 300000
            uint MAC_TABLE_EXPIRE_TIME 600000
            uint MAX_BUFFERING_PACKET_SIZE 480000
            uint MAX_HUB_LINKS 1024
            uint MAX_IP_TABLES 65536
            uint MAX_MAC_TABLES 65536
            uint MAX_SEND_SOCKET_QUEUE_NUM 128
            uint MAX_SEND_SOCKET_QUEUE_SIZE 320000
            uint MAX_STORED_QUEUE_NUM 384
            uint MEM_FIFO_REALLOC_MEM_SIZE 65536
            uint MIN_SEND_SOCKET_QUEUE_SIZE 80000
            uint QUEUE_BUDGET 1024
            uint SELECT_TIME 256
            uint SELECT_TIME_FOR_NAT 30
            uint STORM_CHECK_SPAN 500
            uint STORM_DISCARD_VALUE_END 1024
            uint STORM_DISCARD_VALUE_START 3
        }
        declare ServerTraffic
        {
            declare RecvTraffic
            {
                uint64 BroadcastBytes 42604084
                uint64 BroadcastCount 207782
                uint64 UnicastBytes 2030208533
                uint64 UnicastCount 4625668
            }
            declare SendTraffic
            {
                uint64 BroadcastBytes 41891871
                uint64 BroadcastCount 204651
                uint64 UnicastBytes 552591599
                uint64 UnicastCount 1107498
            }
        }
        declare SyslogSettings
        {
            string HostName $
            uint Port 514
            uint SaveType 0
        }
    }
    declare VirtualHUB
    {
        declare CivHub
        {
            uint64 CreatedTime 1609918077585
            byte HashedPassword removingForPrivacy
            uint64 LastCommTime 1609995876361
            uint64 LastLoginTime 1609942021302
            uint NumLogin 20
            bool Online true
            bool RadiusConvertAllMsChapv2AuthRequestToEap false
            string RadiusRealm $
            uint RadiusRetryInterval 0
            uint RadiusServerPort 1812
            string RadiusSuffixFilter $
            bool RadiusUsePeapInsteadOfEap false
            byte SecurePassword removingForPrivacy
            uint Type 0

            declare AccessList
            {
            }
            declare AdminOption
            {
                uint allow_hub_admin_change_option 0
                uint deny_bridge 0
                uint deny_change_user_password 0
                uint deny_empty_password 0
                uint deny_hub_admin_change_ext_option 0
                uint deny_qos 0
                uint deny_routing 0
                uint max_accesslists 0
                uint max_bitrates_download 0
                uint max_bitrates_upload 0
                uint max_groups 0
                uint max_multilogins_per_user 0
                uint max_sessions 0
                uint max_sessions_bridge 0
                uint max_sessions_client 0
                uint max_sessions_client_bridge_apply 0
                uint max_users 0
                uint no_access_list_include_file 0
                uint no_cascade 0
                uint no_change_access_control_list 0
                uint no_change_access_list 0
                uint no_change_admin_password 0
                uint no_change_cert_list 0
                uint no_change_crl_list 0
                uint no_change_groups 0
                uint no_change_log_config 0
                uint no_change_log_switch_type 0
                uint no_change_msg 0
                uint no_change_users 0
                uint no_delay_jitter_packet_loss 0
                uint no_delete_iptable 0
                uint no_delete_mactable 0
                uint no_disconnect_session 0
                uint no_enum_session 0
                uint no_offline 0
                uint no_online 0
                uint no_query_session 0
                uint no_read_log_file 0
                uint no_securenat 0
                uint no_securenat_enabledhcp 0
                uint no_securenat_enablenat 0
            }
            declare CascadeList
            {
            }
            declare LogSetting
            {
                uint PacketLogSwitchType 4
                uint PACKET_LOG_ARP 0
                uint PACKET_LOG_DHCP 1
                uint PACKET_LOG_ETHERNET 0
                uint PACKET_LOG_ICMP 0
                uint PACKET_LOG_IP 0
                uint PACKET_LOG_TCP 0
                uint PACKET_LOG_TCP_CONN 1
                uint PACKET_LOG_UDP 0
                bool SavePacketLog true
                bool SaveSecurityLog true
                uint SecurityLogSwitchType 4
            }
            declare Message
            {
                string MessageText Hello$20family!$20Let's$20play$20some$20Civ!
            }
            declare Option
            {
                uint AccessListIncludeFileCacheLifetime 30
                uint AdjustTcpMssValue 0
                bool ApplyIPv4AccessListOnArpPacket false
                bool AssignVLanIdByRadiusAttribute false
                bool BroadcastLimiterStrictMode false
                uint BroadcastStormDetectionThreshold 0
                uint ClientMinimumRequiredBuild 0
                bool DenyAllRadiusLoginWithNoVlanAssign false
                uint DetectDormantSessionInterval 0
                bool DisableAdjustTcpMss false
                bool DisableCheckMacOnLocalBridge false
                bool DisableCorrectIpOffloadChecksum false
                bool DisableHttpParsing false
                bool DisableIPParsing false
                bool DisableIpRawModeSecureNAT false
                bool DisableKernelModeSecureNAT false
                bool DisableUdpAcceleration false
                bool DisableUdpFilterForLocalBridgeNic false
                bool DisableUserModeSecureNAT false
                bool DoNotSaveHeavySecurityLogs false
                bool DropArpInPrivacyFilterMode true
                bool DropBroadcastsInPrivacyFilterMode true
                bool FilterBPDU false
                bool FilterIPv4 false
                bool FilterIPv6 false
                bool FilterNonIP false
                bool FilterOSPF false
                bool FilterPPPoE false
                uint FloodingSendQueueBufferQuota 33554432
                bool ManageOnlyLocalUnicastIPv6 true
                bool ManageOnlyPrivateIP true
                uint MaxLoggedPacketsPerMinute 0
                uint MaxSession 0
                bool NoArpPolling false
                bool NoDhcpPacketLogOutsideHub true
                bool NoEnum false
                bool NoIpTable false
                bool NoIPv4PacketLog false
                bool NoIPv6AddrPolling false
                bool NoIPv6DefaultRouterInRAWhenIPv6 true
                bool NoIPv6PacketLog false
                bool NoLookBPDUBridgeId false
                bool NoMacAddressLog true
                bool NoManageVlanId false
                bool NoPhysicalIPOnPacketLog false
                bool NoSpinLockForPacketDelay false
                bool RemoveDefGwOnDhcpForLocalhost true
                uint RequiredClientId 0
                uint SecureNAT_MaxDnsSessionsPerIp 0
                uint SecureNAT_MaxIcmpSessionsPerIp 0
                uint SecureNAT_MaxTcpSessionsPerIp 0
                uint SecureNAT_MaxTcpSynSentPerIp 0
                uint SecureNAT_MaxUdpSessionsPerIp 0
                bool SecureNAT_RandomizeAssignIp false
                bool SuppressClientUpdateNotification false
                bool UseHubNameAsDhcpUserClassOption false
                bool UseHubNameAsRadiusNasId false
                string VlanTypeId 0x8100
                bool YieldAfterStorePacket false
            }
            declare SecureNAT
            {
                bool Disabled true
                bool SaveLog true

                declare VirtualDhcpServer
                {
                    string DhcpDnsServerAddress 192.168.30.1
                    string DhcpDnsServerAddress2 0.0.0.0
                    string DhcpDomainName hsd1.ma.comcast.net
                    bool DhcpEnabled true
                    uint DhcpExpireTimeSpan 7200
                    string DhcpGatewayAddress 192.168.30.1
                    string DhcpLeaseIPEnd 192.168.30.200
                    string DhcpLeaseIPStart 192.168.30.10
                    string DhcpPushRoutes $
                    string DhcpSubnetMask 255.255.255.0
                }
                declare VirtualHost
                {
                    string VirtualHostIp 192.168.30.1
                    string VirtualHostIpSubnetMask 255.255.255.0
                    string VirtualHostMacAddress 5E-AB-10-E2-3E-56
                }
                declare VirtualRouter
                {
                    bool NatEnabled true
                    uint NatMtu 1500
                    uint NatTcpTimeout 1800
                    uint NatUdpTimeout 60
                }
            }
            declare SecurityAccountDatabase
            {
                declare CertList
                {
                }
                declare CrlList
                {
                }
                declare GroupList
                {
                }
                declare IPAccessControlList
                {
                }
                declare UserList
                {
                    declare andrew.stringer
                    {
                        byte AuthNtLmSecureHash removingForPrivacy
                        byte AuthPassword removingForPrivacy
                        uint AuthType 1
                        uint64 CreatedTime 1609918659604
                        uint64 ExpireTime 0
                        uint64 LastLoginTime 0
                        string Note $
                        uint NumLogin 0
                        string RealName Andrew$20Stringer
                        uint64 UpdatedTime 1609918659604

                        declare Traffic
                        {
                            declare RecvTraffic
                            {
                                uint64 BroadcastBytes 0
                                uint64 BroadcastCount 0
                                uint64 UnicastBytes 0
                                uint64 UnicastCount 0
                            }
                            declare SendTraffic
                            {
                                uint64 BroadcastBytes 0
                                uint64 BroadcastCount 0
                                uint64 UnicastBytes 0
                                uint64 UnicastCount 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    declare ben.stringer
                    {
                        byte AuthNtLmSecureHash removingForPrivacy
                        byte AuthPassword removingForPrivacy
                        uint AuthType 1
                        uint64 CreatedTime 1609918539193
                        uint64 ExpireTime 0
                        uint64 LastLoginTime 1609942021302
                        string Note $
                        uint NumLogin 9
                        string RealName Ben$20Stringer
                        uint64 UpdatedTime 1609918539193

                        declare Traffic
                        {
                            declare RecvTraffic
                            {
                                uint64 BroadcastBytes 34929372
                                uint64 BroadcastCount 168190
                                uint64 UnicastBytes 144728245
                                uint64 UnicastCount 186092
                            }
                            declare SendTraffic
                            {
                                uint64 BroadcastBytes 52654
                                uint64 BroadcastCount 866
                                uint64 UnicastBytes 101492350
                                uint64 UnicastCount 168652
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    declare jonathan.stringer
                    {
                        byte AuthNtLmSecureHash removingForPrivacy
                        byte AuthPassword removingForPrivacy
                        uint AuthType 1
                        uint64 CreatedTime 1609918628744
                        uint64 ExpireTime 0
                        uint64 LastLoginTime 1609940474866
                        string Note $
                        uint NumLogin 2
                        string RealName Jonathan$20Stringer
                        uint64 UpdatedTime 1609918628744

                        declare Traffic
                        {
                            declare RecvTraffic
                            {
                                uint64 BroadcastBytes 822089
                                uint64 BroadcastCount 4507
                                uint64 UnicastBytes 78066192
                                uint64 UnicastCount 64377
                            }
                            declare SendTraffic
                            {
                                uint64 BroadcastBytes 2297
                                uint64 BroadcastCount 7
                                uint64 UnicastBytes 3227082
                                uint64 UnicastCount 33286
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    declare lena.schaller
                    {
                        byte AuthNtLmSecureHash removingForPrivacy
                        byte AuthPassword removingForPrivacy
                        uint AuthType 1
                        uint64 CreatedTime 1609918701879
                        uint64 ExpireTime 0
                        uint64 LastLoginTime 1609941914961
                        string Note $
                        uint NumLogin 9
                        string RealName Lena$20Schaller
                        uint64 UpdatedTime 1609918701879

                        declare Traffic
                        {
                            declare RecvTraffic
                            {
                                uint64 BroadcastBytes 6078133
                                uint64 BroadcastCount 31362
                                uint64 UnicastBytes 131522522
                                uint64 UnicastCount 153793
                            }
                            declare SendTraffic
                            {
                                uint64 BroadcastBytes 84586
                                uint64 BroadcastCount 1612
                                uint64 UnicastBytes 71285928
                                uint64 UnicastCount 118902
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            declare Traffic
            {
                declare RecvTraffic
                {
                    uint64 BroadcastBytes 42604084
                    uint64 BroadcastCount 207782
                    uint64 UnicastBytes 2030208533
                    uint64 UnicastCount 4625668
                }
                declare SendTraffic
                {
                    uint64 BroadcastBytes 41891871
                    uint64 BroadcastCount 204651
                    uint64 UnicastBytes 552591599
                    uint64 UnicastCount 1107498
                }
            }
        }
    }
    declare VirtualLayer3SwitchList
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not say what you have seen with Wireshark, this is just a guess about what went wrong.

The mechanism of this multiplayer play is probably like this.

1. The host listens and waits for others to discover and join the game.
2. The joiner discovers the host by sending multicast packets (e.g. via mDNS) over the local network.
3. Once the host receives one of those packets, it replies to the new joiner via unicast.
4. The connection is established and game starts.

However, for some reason the joiner only sends discovery packets over local network, which includes WiFi and LAN but not VPN. So if the joiner is on VPN it can never reach the host.

Please share your observation with Wireshark so I can answer more accurately.